# Azure Service Fabric actor reminder update?

Tags: azure, actor, azure-service-fabric, reminders

Suppose I have a reliable actor that registers a reminder in `OnActivateAsync`. This reminder has a `period` that is retrieved from some persistent storage. After some time the actor is garbage-collected.

After some more time the actor is called or the reminder fires and `OnActivateAsync` is called by the runtime. In the meantime, I updated the reminder `period` in persistent storage.

What happens now? I attempt to register the reminder again but with a different `period`. Will the reminder be updated with the new `period`?

Another case is an update of the actor. Suppose the `period` is hard-coded but a new version of the actor uses a different `period`. What happens now when `OnActivateAsync` is called and the reminder is registered again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to register an existing reminder again, it will be updated. From `RegisterReminderAsync` documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.runtime.actorbase.registerreminderasync?view=azure-dotnet):

> Existing reminders can also be updated by calling this method again.

Answer (score 2):

So when the first time your reminder fires, it's up to you to check if the period has been updated and the unregister the existing reminder and register a new one.
You can't update the existing reminder - use `GetReminder` to see if it exists and then unregister it and create a new one.

```

```
 var reminder = GetReminder(reminderName);       
  if (reminder != null)                           
  {                                               
      // do something with it...    
  }
```

```

In the case when the actor code is upgraded and you have a hard coded period in code (that's changed), with the guard, you wouldn't register/update the existing reminder.